# Is there a way to query for PalletId from polkadot-js apps?

Tags: pallet

For example, when specifying a `Multilocation` we could need to look up a `PalletInstance` for a particular pallet. In that case, besides looking at the source code, is there an easier call I can make via `apps` to find out what it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can query the [Constants using PolkadotJS](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/kusama/constants/).

See below an example to query the palletId for the treasury pallet in Polkadot (and the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/polkadot/constants/#palletid-framesupportpalletid-2)):

```js
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const palletId = api.consts.treasury.palletId;
console.log(`${palletId.toHuman()} `);
```

Comment: For some reason, not all pallets have the `palletId` field.